# Android GCMNetworkManager not executing while device idle

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I've used GCMNetworkManager to schedule a service which runs every minute. It's working fine while the device is active, but once the phone goes idle, I'm getting mixed results. (I tested three devices today with the service running for the whole day, it currently just writes the date/time to a file).

Galaxy S6, the task fired for around 4 hours, then stopped until I turned the screen on.
HTC One M9, the task fired on and off (but not consistently) for around 3 hours, then stopped until I turned the screen on.
HTC One M7, the task stopped firing pretty soon after the phone went idle and never ran again all day.

I want this service to run while idle, am I doing something wrong?

```
    long periodSecs = 60L; // the task should be executed every one minute
    long flexSecs = 30L; // the task can run as early as -30 seconds from the scheduled time
    String tag = "TASK_SCAN";

    PeriodicTask periodic = new PeriodicTask.Builder()
            .setService(MyService.class)
            .setPeriod(periodSecs)
            .setFlex(flexSecs)
            .setTag(tag)
            .setPersisted(true)
            .setRequiredNetwork(Task.NETWORK_STATE_CONNECTED)
            .setRequiresCharging(false)
            .setUpdateCurrent(true)
            .build();

    mGcmNetworkManager.schedule(periodic);
```

Comment: When the device dozes the network might not be available there fore your service will not run.

Comment: Well so far I'm not even using the network. So maybe I should change the requiredNetwork parameter and see if I have more luck running the task - but ultimately I will need to send data over the network.